# Proving Schröder–Bernstein theorem by defining a function from a power set of a set to itself.

Tags: functions, set-theory

Theorem:
let A,B  be sets such that exists injection $ f:A\to B $ and injection $ g:B\to A$  then exsits a bijection $h:A\to B $

My attepmt to prove:

Define: $ F:P(A)\to P(A) $ by :

for every $ x\subseteq A $

$ F(X)= A/g[B/f[X]]  $

**claim:**
exists $ X\subseteq A $ such that $ F[X]=X $

now in that case, we can define for every  $ a\in A $ 
$ h: A\to B $   by:

$ h(a) = f(a) $ if $a\in X $ and

$ h(a) =g^{-1}(a) $ if $ a\notin X $

Its not hard to show that h is bijection. But im having trouble proving that X realy exists.

Thats my attempt for proving that such X exists:

$ g: B\to A $ is injective

then $ g^{-1}: A\to B $ is surjective

define: $ g[B]= A' $ then $ g^{-1}: A'\to B $ is bijection.

now define $ A_0=A/A' $

$f[A_0]=B_0 $

and for every $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ :

$A_{n+1}=g[B_n] $  and  $ B_n=f[A_n] $

now once again define:

$ N=\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i $

So $ A/N $ satisfies that  $ F[A/N]=A/N $

thats true $ \iff $

$ A/N=A/g[B/f[A/N]] $   $ \iff $

$ N= \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = g[B/f[A/N] $

now i tried to prove it by showing that $ N = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i \subseteq g[B/f[A/N] $  and also $ g[B/f[A/N] \subseteq N $

So i start with $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ and i want to show that $ n\in  g[B/f[A/N] $   we know that $ n\in \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i $ so we have some $ i\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $n\in A_i $

but if $ i=0 $ then we get a contradiction to my claim.

is my claim even correct ($ A/N $ really satisfies $ F[A/N]=A/N $ )? if it does, any ideas of how to prove it will be helpful.

Comment: I think where you have slashes you want the set subtraction operator $\setminus$. You can get it using `\setminus`.

Comment: You should be able to find similar questions on the site, by the way.